# DOM loading before the promise defer completes

Tags: angularjs, promise

I have a model that I am using to hold my data in angular:

```
var FuelProcessingModel = function (carrierService) {
    this.myArray = [];
};
```

That model has an array of MyObjects that I get from the DB:

```
var MyObject = function () {
    //stuff
}
```

I update this using a REST call:

```
$scope.add = function () {
        var myObject = new MyObject();
        fuelProcessingService.add(myObject).then(function(result) {
            $scope.model.MyObjects.push(result.data);
        });

    };
```

Here you can see I want to push the result to the array so that it is added on the screen. But the problem is the DOM loads before that happens.

service to hit the Server:

```
 this.add = function (myObject) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http({
            method: "POST",
            url: "theServer",
            data: myObject,

        }).success(function (data) {
            deferred.resolve(data);
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    }
```

The REST service adds to the Database and then returns the updated object
I thought that $q.defer() would cause the DOM to wait to load until the result is returned so that the newly added item shows up.

What am I missing?

**UPDATE**

I tried doing this but I still have the same problem. The push call is not being called before the DOM loads the page, so the user never sees the added item.

```
this.add = function (myObject) {
        return $http({
            method: "POST",
            url: "theServer",
            data: myObject,

        }).success(function (data) {
            return data;
        });
```

Html that creates and uses the object

```
<div ng-repeat="myObject in model.MyObjects" style="margin-bottom: 2%">
        //A table of myObjectData

    <button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="add()">Add My Object</button>
</div>
```

Comment: if u want view to wait until http finishes you need to do it manually, for example show wait dialog and hide it in success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what happens in Angular.

- Initial html is rendered (also called template html).
- Angular boostraps, and then does the necessary binding and the view is updated.
- Angular watches for changes and if there is a change in data, view is updated automatically.

When you bind the array to the view the, it renders what is available. When you add some new element to the array later the view should automatically update. You do not need to bother with creating your own promise just do

`return $http...`

Comment: I tried without the defer and the page does not show the added element to the array unless you refresh the page

Comment: Add the html binding content and what object is being bound to.

Comment: Done, and the Object that it is being bound to is at the top of the post

Comment: It should work, the only thing that i would check more is that the then callback is being called and result.data points to the same record that has been created.